# How sorting works in ruby on rails? when there are multiple fields to sort in a single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

I have a model with the fields price, min_price,max_price, discount,in my product table. if I want to execute ascending descending orders, how that will get executed when we apply for an order on multiple fields. for example like below.

```
@products = Product.order("price asc").order("min_price desc").order("max_price asc").order("updated_at asc") (Query might be wrong but for reference im adding)
```

will it order as per the order sequence ?

Answer (score 2):

If you append `.to_sql` to that, it will show the generated SQL so you can investigate yourself.

I tried a similar query:

```
Book.select(:id).order("id asc").order("pub_date desc").to_sql
=> "SELECT \"books\".\"id\" FROM \"books\" ORDER BY id asc, pub_date desc"
```

You might instead:

```
Book.select(:id).order(id: :asc, pub_date: :desc).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"books\".\"id\" FROM \"books\" ORDER BY \"books\".\"id\" ASC, \"books\".\"pub_date\" DESC"
```

... which you see adds the table name in, so is more reliable when if you are accessing multiple tables

Comment: `order(id: :asc)` is also arguably more portable then `order("books.id ASC")` as ActiveRecord will handle quoting the table name and column so that it works in garbage dbs.